# How to use an android phone as a modem?

Tags: 12.04, android, mobile-broadband

I have activated my mobile internet on Samsung's phone running on android 2.3. How to use my mobile phone's internet in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: Settings>Wireless>Thetering>USB Connection.

Comment: You need assistance on either: ***How to configure Android phone as WiFi hot-spot.*** OR ***How to configure Android phone as USB modem (tethering)***.  Then you may **also** need to know how to configure Ubuntu to use this connection.

Answer (score 2):

As I remember the tethering features of 2.3 are a little weak. Back then I made it work using [EasyTether](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html).